# Search for a string in a file and then find the the previous lines that match a diffrent string

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have some hardware load balancer configurations that I would like to parse using any available linux tools (e.g. sed, awk, grep, etc.).

I would like to search for the phrase `address 10.1.104.164` and I would like to know the pool it resides within. For example if we searched for `10.1.104.164` I would like it to return:

```
ltm pool pool_10.1.105.30_80
ltm pool pool_10.1.105.31_80
```

Here is a sample of the file I am searching:

```
ltm pool pool_10.1.105.30_80 {
    load-balancing-mode observed-member
    members {
        node_10.1.104.163:http {
            address 10.1.104.163
            session monitor-enabled
            state up
        }
        node_10.1.104.164:http {
            address 10.1.104.164
            session monitor-enabled
            state up
        }
    }
    monitor http_200_OK
}
ltm pool pool_10.1.105.31_80 {
    load-balancing-mode observed-member
    members {
        node_10.1.104.163:http {
            address 10.1.104.163
            session monitor-enabled
            state up
        }
        node_10.1.104.164:http {
            address 10.1.104.164
            session monitor-enabled
            state up
        }
    }
    monitor http_200_OK
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Edit: Spelling and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v tgt="address 10.1.104.164" '
    /^ltm pool/ { pool=$0; sub(/ *{ *$/,"",pool) }
    index($0" ",tgt" ") { print pool }
' file
ltm pool pool_10.1.105.30_80
ltm pool pool_10.1.105.31_80
```

Comment: This is better.

Comment: Thank you! However, I ran into one issue, Lets suppose the address line is "address 10.1.104.16", if we run this awk command it will match for 10.1.104.16 and 10.1.104.164 which will yield incorrect results. I think we need to set tgt="address 10.1.104.164" to have an end of line identifier like this tgt="address 10.1.104.164$", however, this is not the correct syntax.

Comment: I tweaked the script to fix that. For future questions - when posting sample input/output it's extremely useful if you put thought into it and come up with edge cases like the one you've now mentioned when first posting your question so we can consider them when trying to help you come up with a solution rather than discovering and debugging them later.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -0777 -lne 'while (/^(ltm pool pool_[\d._]+)(.*?)(?=^\})/gms){ 
                         $m=$1; $t=$2; 
                         print "$m\n" if ($t =~ /address 10\.1\.104\.164/)}' file
ltm pool pool_10.1.105.30_80
ltm pool pool_10.1.105.31_80
```